# What is "compiled resource datatype"?

Tags: android, kotlin

I was going through Android Development Docs and there was "compiled resource datatype". What does this mean?

Comment: Hi, could you add a link to the aforementioned docs in your question so we get more context about it?

Answer (score 1):

A **Compiled Resource Datatype** is the jvm types the resources are compiled into.

If you look into the [docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/available-resources), you can find many examples.

Examples:

1. A layout XML file has a compiled resource type of a [View](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/layout-resource).
2. A menu resource (xml) has a compiled resource type of a [Menu](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/menu-resource).
3. A bitmap drawable (.jpeg, .pngs) into [BitmapDrawable](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource#Bitmap).

The compiled resource datatype are the types which you will use to change, fetch, manipulate the datatypes. For example, loading a drawable using the Resource ID (can be found at the `res/drawable`), but if you want to apply tinting or shadows you need to use the [BitmapDrawable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/BitmapDrawable) methods.

Think of it as the medium of manipulating programmatically the files that can be found under the `res/**` directory.

Probably there is more to it than this, but for development purposes this would be a sufficient, I believe, explanation.